# What is the difference in meaning between "discrete" and "distinct"?

Tags: differences, adjectives

What is the difference in meaning between "discrete" and "distinct"?

It seems as though discrete indicates a stronger degree of separation between the two things being compared, whereas distinct seems to mean easily discernible.

Comment: To my mind, "discrete" means "separate, not overlapping", and "distinct" means "able to be distinguished, easily definable as two individual entities". Hard to find examples that make those differences clear. Perhaps if you had to do the same task twice, they'd be discrete tasks, but not distinct. And conversely, if you have two roles (say, database administrator, and data entry), you might say the roles are distinct, but I wouldn't say you have two discrete roles.

Comment: And there are cases where one word doesn't fit. "Two distinct shades of red", but not "two discrete shades of red".